# Tkinter inherited class not behaving properly on Ubuntu

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I've created a simple class inheriting directly from the root window, it works perfectly on a Mac machine. However, when I try to run it on my own, Ubuntu based machine, it crashes with the following error. What is causing this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/estilen/Dropbox/Python/email_viewer/dialog.py", line 15, in <module>
    Dialog('This is definitely working')
  File "/home/estilen/Dropbox/Python/email_viewer/dialog.py", line 7, in __init__
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, dialog_message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1871, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "This is definitely working"
```

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Dialog(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, dialog_message):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, dialog_message)
        self.geometry('400x100')
        label = tk.Label(self, text=dialog_message)
        label.pack(anchor='center', side='top', pady=10)
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dialog('This is definitely working')
```

Comment: Try changing the first line of `__init__` to the following `tk.Tk.__init__(self, className=dialog_message)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tk.Tk.__init__(self, dialog_message)
```

This doesn't look right to me. The first positional argument to the Tk constructor is [`screenName`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk). If you don't want to display your window on a display that's named "This is definitely working", then don't supply that argument.

```
tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

... Or, more idiomatically,

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: How come does my implementation work on the Mac machine though?

Comment: @LukaszSalitra I thing the argument is just ignored for some reason.

Comment: I suspect that if an OS doesn't support named displays, it simply ignores that argument. If Macs don't support named displays, that would explain it

Comment: @Kevin Makes sense. Thanks.